# Can't play sound in java using clip

Tags: java, eclipse, file, audio, avaudiofile

I want to play some sound in java using this code bellow. That sound is in WAV format so I think that this code should work fine, but instead of playing sound it simply does nothing. There is no even error on my console. So can someone help me to make this code play sound. (this sound is included inside one package in my src file)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jovan\\Desktop\\song.wav");

                AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

                clip.open(inputStream);

                clip.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: you have to start the thread thats probably the reason

Comment: Still nothing happenes

Comment: you have to show the whole program - I've done enough guessing for the day

Comment: but this is my whole program just without imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the clip to play and end. You can also create some Listener but that's more complicated. When the clip finishes playing (isActive() is false) you end.

```
public class P {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

            System.out.println("started");

                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                File file = new File(".......................wav");

                AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

                clip.open(inputStream);

                clip.start();

                while(clip.isOpen()) {
                  try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
                  if(!clip.isActive()) break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just started this thread, so create an object:

```
import java.io.*;
import  javax.sound.sampled.*;

class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread b= new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    File file = new File("G:/skit/msg.wav");
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                    clip.open(inputStream);
                    clip.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        b.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing happenes